# WPF-How to change number of decimal places in Textbox from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application with lots of  textboxes storing currency values for which i used Infragistics control ,but there are issues with infragistics dll so decided to move to native controls like TextBox.In infragistics i could set number of decimal places in code behind using this for 3 decimal places

```
txtInvoiceAmount.Mask = "{double:-15.3}";
```

using this for 2 decimal places

```
txtInvoiceAmount.Mask = "{double:-15.2}";
```

Is there an easy way to set TextBox to accept 2 or 3 decimal places in code behind in WPF?

Comment: You may want to use the MaskedTextbox component, it comes with a native feature to customize input masks.
<wpfx:MaskedTextBox Width="200" Height="30" Mask="(000) 000-0000" Value="4849898984"/> 
In your case you could set the mask programmatically : MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "###.##"

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to set TextBox to accept 2 or 3 decimal places in code behind in WPF?

No, there isn't.

The built-in `TextBox` control doesn't handle numbers or decimals. It just stores a `string` in its `Text` property.

You may want to take a look at the `MaskedTextBox` control in the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit).